# what is the proper way to override chef recipe attributes?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I am adding this [Solr Chef recipe](https://github.com/dwradcliffe/chef-solr) an [existing vagrant box](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/vdd/tree/) . I want to override the version attribute [here](https://github.com/dwradcliffe/chef-solr/blob/master/attributes/default.rb) . Do I override these variables in one of the json files or it has to be overridden in the recipe attributes file itself?

Answer (score 3):

For your use case it's ok to override it in Vagrantfile directly. Check more info about chef solo and vagrant [here](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html).

**tldr;**

Just provide `chef.json` option with attributes in your Vagrantfile like:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
# ...
    chef.json = {
     "solr" => {
       "version" => "4.6.1"
      }
    }
  end
end
```

In general practise it's common to set attributes inside roles, or by creating [wrapper cookbooks](https://www.chef.io/blog/2013/12/03/doing-wrapper-cookbooks-right/) around community ones, and with that there is no need for changing original source code.